# dplyr 0.7.0 tidyeval in packages

Tags: r, dplyr, r-package, rlang, tidyeval

**Preamble**

I commonly use `dplyr` in my packages. Prior to `0.7.0`, I was using the underscored versions of `dplyr` verbs to avoid NOTEs during `R CMD CHECK`. For example, the code:

```
x <- tibble::tibble(v = 1:3, w = 2)
y <- dplyr::filter(x, v > w)
```

would have yielded the `R CMD CHECK` NOTE:

```
* checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
no visible binding for global variable ‘v’
```

By comparison, using the standard evaluation version:

```
y <- dplyr::filter_(x, ~v > w)
```

yielded no such NOTE.

However, in `dplyr 0.7.0`, the vignette [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) says that the appropriate syntax for including `dplyr` functions in packages (to avoid NOTEs) is:

```
y <- dplyr::filter(x, .data$v > .data$w)
```

Consequently, the [news file](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md) says that "the underscored version of each main verb is no longer needed, and so these functions have been deprecated (but remain around for backward compatibility)."

**Question**

The vignette says that the above new syntax will not yield `R CMD check` NOTES, "provided that you’ve also imported `rlang::.data` with `@importFrom rlang .data`." However, when I run the code:

```
y <- dplyr::filter(x, rlang::.data$v > rlang::.data$w)
Evaluation error: Object `From` not found in data.
```

Is this error similar to the following?

```
y <- dplyr::filter(x, v == dplyr::n())
Evaluation error: This function should not be called directly.
```

Namely, for some functions, calling them prefixed with the package yields errors? (Something to do with whether or not they've been exported, perhaps?)

**Comment**

As an aside, is there a less verbose way of writing package-friendly `dplyr` functions with the new syntax in 0.7.0? In particular, the syntax for `dplyr >=0.7.0`:

```
y <- dplyr::filter(x, .data$v > .data$w)
```

is more verbose than the syntax for `dplyr <0.7.0`:

```
y <- dplyr::filter_(x, ~v > w)
```

and the verbosity increases as more variables are referenced. However, I don't want to use the less verbose syntax with the underscored version, as it is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for some functions, calling them prefixed with the package yields errors?

That's right, but we could make them work to make things more predictable. You can file a github issue for this feature.

> is there a less verbose way of writing package-friendly dplyr functions with the new syntax in 0.7.0?

The alternative is to declare all your column symbols to R, e.g. within a `globalVariables(c("v", "w"))` statement somewhere in your package.

Ideally, R should know about NSE functions and never warn for unknown symbols in those cases.

Comment: Thanks. Should I file the issue under `dplyr` or `rlang`?

Comment: you can file at dplyr please

Answer (score 2):

Another work-around is to add lines such as

```
v <- NULL; # mark as not an unbound global reference
```

just above your expressions that are generating CRAN checks.  It is no less accurate (column names are not in fact global variables) and has somewhat limited scope.